# Installation directory by command line for installer file

Tags: command-line, installation, nsis

I create installer file by NSIS.I want get  installation directory by commandline.
I used syntax such as /D=E:\ or /D=E:  but installation directory any changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/D` (It must be the last token on the commandline and it must be a unquoted absolute path):

```
MySetup.exe /S /D=C:\Program Files\Foo Bar\Baz
```

If you want to allow installs to the root of a volume you need to put `AllowRootDirInstall true` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

**/D** switch is intended for Silent installs.

Use **InstallDir** from your script to change directory.

Comment: /D will override InstallDir & InstallDirRegKey and is not just intended for silent installs...

Answer (score 1):

I create uninstaller file but uninstaller can not clean files.

```
ExeWait '"$INSTDIR\Farayand\FarayandLibrary\dokanctl.exe" /r a' $0
RMDir /r $INSTDIR\Farayand\FarayandLibrary
RMDir $INSTDIR\Farayand
${if} ${RunningX64}
   ${DisableX64FSRedirection}
     Delete $SYSDIR\drivers\dokan.sys
   ${EnableX64FSRedirection}
${Else}
      Delete $SYSDIR\drivers\dokan.sys
${ElseIF}
```

dokan.sys cleaned when uninstall run.but farayandLibrary folder and content in folder dont remove.